# 135mm Hub Bodies that accept XD driver

Tags: freehub

So I'm looking around for a way to convert my three ring crank 8 speed drive train to a single cog 12 speed setup. I currently have a 135mm hub. My idea is to buy a new wheel and a compatible hub and lace it up. The issue I am having is locating such an animal as far as a 135mm Hub that will accept the XD body. I have looked a SRAM 900 bodies but they are thru the roof and then adding the XD body well my bike isn't going on any title rides.. Any ideas on how to put this together on a budget? I have the wheel so the focus is in the hub..

Comment: Steve, are you talking about a 135x12 or 135x9 hub? Also, check out [Sunrace CSMZ90](http://www.sunrace.com/en/products/detail/csmz90), it uses a regular hyperglide freehub body you already have, so no need for a new wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the 12 speed group from Sunrace? https://singletrackworld.com/2018/04/found-sunrace-has-a-new-12-speed-mz90-11-50t-cassette/

Or just released from SRAM is the new 12 speed NX group that uses at standard freehub:
https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/family/nx-eagle

Comment: Hi, Dean, thanks for the useful answer.. Yes it is a 135x9 I have been looking at SRAM 900 hubs w/ xd driver body for 135mm QR that would put me into the GX series. I did look at the NX. The cassette is steel and pretty heavy compared to it's counterparts.. I think I will just have to build it up piece at a time.. Thanks again I will check out sunrace..

Comment: Sunrace does make a nice 12 speed cassette that would also work for you.

Comment: Thanks Dean.. I went ahead and purchased a SRAM 900 Hub w/ XD body and a i29 WBT rim I figured there might be a case for the advancement of the drive train system in the XD idea. My bike can stand to lose some pounds and without breaking the bank on carbon, it seems like lighter components are the way to go..

Comment: Cool man now you can run the sweet SRAM XD cassettes!

Comment: Yah Man.. I'm very happy to finally have made a decision.. I'm looking for spokes etc.. It will be my first wheel build and will be interesting.. Also with all the new cassettes rolling out I'll be watching for a fresh take off of a 12 speed GX Eagle or maybe X1 if I'm lucky.. I'm going in for a injury repair, which will put me out for the rest of the summer as far as riding but I'll be building and looking forward to the late fall.. Thanks for the conversation dean..